# Processing noisy unlabelled textual data for specific Named Entity Recognition

Tags: parsing, nlp, data-analysis

I am trying to extract some very specific info. i.e Organization names from very noisy data. an example is as follows:

`AAC: 1233 BOB'S ELECTRONICS 12\323 ENTRY-123`

The only important part to me is the BOB'S ELECTRONICS. Is there a good parser that handles noisy data like this and gives chunked results? Like so:

`(Bob's Electronics, Organization)`

P.S. -  Stanford Core NLP gives me `(Bob, person)`

Comment: do you have your own dataset ?

Comment: Yes, I do. I can't share all the data though.